# Change background color of active tabs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tabs, background-color

Using Bootstrap v2.3.2, I am trying to change the default background color for the active tabs.  I've tried to set as below, but it doesn't work:

```
.nav-tabs > .active > a,
.nav-tabs > .active > a:hover,
.nav-tabs > .active > a:focus
{
    color: #555555;
    background-color: red;  
}
```

Any advice as to why this isn't working, or how to fix it?

Comment: Did you try the solution I posted?

Answer (score 30):

In the Bootstrap v2.3.2 CSS file, the CSS is as follows for your snippet:

```
        .nav-tabs > li.active > a,
        .nav-tabs > li.active > a:hover,
        .nav-tabs > li.active > a:focus {
          color: #555555;
          cursor: default;
          background-color: #ffffff;
          border: 1px solid #dddddd;
          border-bottom-color: transparent;
          }
```

Compare this to your CSS snippet as you can see, you are missing the `li` selector before `.active` selector. 
Your CSS is correct however it does not work as the specificity in the Bootstrap CSS is more.
So Just change your code snippet to by increasing specificity:

```
        .nav-tabs > li.active > a,
        .nav-tabs > li.active > a:hover,
        .nav-tabs > li.active > a:focus{
            color: #555555;
            background-color: red;  
        }
```

Now your browser when it renders the page will choose your CSS snippet.
You can see an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/yyPrg/

You can read up on CSS specificity here:
http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/
and  here:
http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Answer (score 0):

In case of Bootstrap 3 and above, following css worked for me (no anchor tag):

```
ul.nav-tabs > li.active {
    background-color: #e9ecef;
    border: 1px #e9ecef;
    border-radius: .25rem;
    border-bottom-left-radius:0;
    border-bottom-right-radius:0;
}
```

*Note: This also solves active tab highlight problem for ui-bootstrap plug-in's tab.*